# How to properly construct query with in_ operator

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have an SQL update query with IN statement which is executed via SQLAlchemy. Unfortunately current implementation uses string interpolation, which I'd like to replace with more secure option.

```py
session.execute('''
        UPDATE servers SET
            cpu_cores=st.cpu_cores,
            cpu_mhz=st.cpu_mhz,
            ram_mb=st.ram_mb
        FROM servers
        WHERE
            server.provider_id IN (%s)
''' % ','.join([ ... ]))
```

Is it possible to replace `%` operator with `in_` method here? Or I should re-implement this query using `session.query`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is to make it more secure, you can still interpolate in the param placeholders:

```
session.execute("""UPDATE ... WHERE server.provider_id IN (%s)""" % ",".join("?" * len(provider_ids)), provider_ids)
```

The `?` is the placeholder, and varies depending on the [`paramstyle`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) of the DB driver you are using.

Otherwise, the easiest way is to translate this into a `session.query` or `update().where()` construct.